# None english voice in SpeechSynthesis

Tags: c#, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to get SpeechSynthesis to work with a none english Language.

First I've tried to set the culture info:

```
        var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer
        {
            Volume = 100,
            Rate = 0
        };

        var text = "Dette er en test";
        var builder = new PromptBuilder(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-dk"));
        builder.AppendText(text);
        speech.SpeakAsync(builder);
```

But it is still an english voice there are chosen.

Then I've made at small program listing the installed voices:

```
    using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Installed voices -");
        foreach (var voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
            var info = voice.VoiceInfo;
            Console.WriteLine(" Name:          " + info.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(" Culture:       " + info.Culture);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Supported languages listed using C# :

[image]

But when looking in windows, I see more voices. Among them a Danish one (Helle)

[image]

The display language in my Windows is English. But I've also tried my program on a Windows with Danish as display language. Same result: Still an English voice chosen.

So in short how do I make SpeechSynthesis speak Danish?